# What's the algorithm behind markov classifier in Classify function for text classification?

Tags: implementation-details, markov-chains, machine-learning

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/find-which-author-wrote-a-text.html

The above url show the use of `Classify` function to do text classification. The classifier information marked as `markov`. Is it actually hidden markov process or anything else? I can not find enough informations about using markov process as classifier. Can anyone provide some helpful and easy to understand resources for mathematica markov classifer?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it's traditional hidden Markov models in natural language processing. [Here](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/) is some related material. You can also find online courses on this topic.